# How to get random idrow from two tables with different % chance from SQlite in Java application?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm writing application in JavaFX with Scene Builder. My database is SQlite. To browse and edit SQLite I use DB Browser

I have a table "Cards" and table "sentences" in one database file

[image: Table Cards]

[image: Table senteces]

I have a button "Random" and two textArias. When I click on the button the method is called. The method takes random idrow from table "Cards" and set text from columns to textArias in my application.

I wanna make a chance when click on the button: 70% chance to select random idrow from table "Cards" and 30% chance to select random idrow from table "sentences".

Example:If I click on button 10 times. My TextArias will show text from columns from table "Cards" - 7 times

text from columns in table "sentences" - 3 times

**How to select random idrow with percentage chance 70/30 from two tables?**

Class where I store a query (this query select random idrow and prevent from empty rows):

```
package src.card;

public class PersistentQueries {


  private String sqlRandom = "SELECT * FROM Cards where rowid = (ABS(RANDOM()) % (SELECT (SELECT MAX(rowid) from Cards)+1)) or rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM Cards) ORDER BY rowid LIMIT 1";


  public String getSqlRandom() {
   return sqlRandom;
  }

  public void setSqlRandom(String sqlRandom) {
   this.sqlRandom = sqlRandom;
  }
}
```

**Class QuestionController:**

```
@FXML  private TextArea ta_questText, ta_answerText;
@FXML  private Button btnRand;

Cards cards = new Cards();
PersistentQueries pq = new PersistentQueries();

ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;

@FXML void randomCard(ActionEvent event) {

try {
  Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
  pst = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getSqlRandom());

  rs = pst.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()) {

    ta_questText.setText(rs.getString("question"));
    ta_answerText.setText(rs.getString("answer"));
  }

  pst.close();
  rs.close();
  conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
```

**EDIT:**

According to @MikeT answer I made a special query and placed it to one class with all my queries :

```
public class PersistentQueries {

private String sqlRandomCat1 = "SELECT CASE WHEN ((abs(random()) % 10) + 1) > 7 THEN (SELECT 'category1' || rowid FROM category1 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1) ELSE (SELECT 'sentences' || rowid FROM sentences ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1) END ";

public String getSqlRandomCat1() {
return sqlRandomCat1;
}

 public void setSqlRandomCat1(String sqlRandomCat1) {
this.sqlRandomCat1 = sqlRandomCat1;
 }

}
```

In my `QuestionController` class, I created object of that class with queries:

```
PersistentQueries pq = new PersistentQueries();
```

and then created method that will take text from columns in tables and set this text to text areas:

```
@FXML void randomCard(ActionEvent event) {

try {
  Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
  pst = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getSqlRandomCat1());

  rs = pst.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()) {

    ta_questText.setText(rs.getString("question"));
    ta_answerText.setText(rs.getString("answer"));
  }

  conn.close();

   } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I also duplicated columns 'question' and 'answer' in "sentences" table, because it didn't have those columns. So, those columns are just duplicate text from 'sentence' column

[image: sentences table]

But after launching the application, I get these errors:

```
java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'question'
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.findColumn(JDBC3ResultSet.java:48)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getString(JDBC3ResultSet.java:443)
at src.card.QuestController.randomCard(QuestController.java:454)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at 
  ...
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**

What if I'll use same query as I used before to generate random idrow from one table and make some method like this:

- generate some random chance
- if a chance is < 70 - call a query that will take random id row from table "Cards" and apply text from columns to my textArea
- if a chance is >70 and <100 - call a query that will take random idrow from table "sentences" and apply text from columns to my textArea

But I don't know how to make this method.

Can you help me?

Comment: please a) don't ask several questions in one - it's difficult to answer b) provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem c) unrelated to your problem: learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: Sorry for that! I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query based upon the following :-

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ((abs(random()) % 10) + 1) > 7 THEN 
            // 70% chance
            (SELECT rowid FROM cards ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1)  
        ELSE 
            // 30% chance
            (SELECT rowid FROM sentences ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1) 
    END
;
```

However, you would then not know from which table the rowid came from so perhaps you could differentiate by using `'c'||rowid` along with `'s'||rowid` to differentiate between the tables.

Comment: The above only output/produces 1 column namely **rowid**, enough to get all the other columns but note that without an indicator (hence the bit about prefixing the rowid with c for cards and s for sentences to indicate the table). As the question was * .... to select random idrow*

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOUND!**

I've created generated random number like this in the method:

```
int n = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
```

and I've made a condition:

```
if(n < 70) {
//70 % chance to set Text from Category 1
}

else if (n < 80) {
//30% chance to set Text from table "sentences"
}
```

My full code look like this:

**In class where I hold all SQLite queries:**

```
public class PersistentQueries {

private String sqlRandomCat1 = "SELECT * FROM Category1 where rowid = (ABS(RANDOM()) % (SELECT (SELECT MAX(rowid) from Category1)+1)) or rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM Category1) ORDER BY rowid LIMIT 1";
private String sqlRandomSent = "SELECT * FROM sentences where rowid = (ABS(RANDOM()) % (SELECT (SELECT MAX(rowid) from sentences)+1)) or rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM sentences) ORDER BY rowid LIMIT 1";

  public String getSqlRandomCat1() {return sqlRandomCat1;}

  public void setSqlRandomCat1(String sqlRandomCat1) {this.sqlRandomCat1 = sqlRandomCat1;}

  public String getSqlRandomSent() {return sqlRandomSent;}

  public void setSqlRandomSent(String sqlRandomSent) {this.sqlRandomSent = sqlRandomSent;}


}
```

**Controller:**

```
@FXML
  void randomCard(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {

    int n = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    if (n < 70) {
      Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
      pst = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getSqlRandomCat1());

      rs = pst.executeQuery();
      while (rs.next()) {

        ta_questText.setText(rs.getString("question"));
        ta_answerText.setText(rs.getString("answer"));

      }
    } else if (n < 80) {
      ta_questText.setText("");
      Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
      pst = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getSqlRandomSent());

      rs = pst.executeQuery();
      while (rs.next()) {

        ta_questText.setText("");
        ta_answerText.setText(rs.getString("sentence"));
      }

    }
  }
```